# How to get a pandas Series dummy representation of one value

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, categorical-data, dummy-variable

Suppose I have 5 different categories

```
categories = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

Is it possible to use Pandas' `get_dummies` to obtain a dummy representation of one element ? Namely, suppose i have

```
element = 'a'
```

Becomes

```
Series({
 'a' : 1, 
 'b' : 0,
 'c' : 0,
 'd' : 0,
 'e' : 0,
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this helps. This will generate dummies of all categories.

```
categories = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}

categoriesSeries = pd.Series(list(categories))
pd.get_dummies(categoriesSeries)
```

Result

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  0  0  0  0  1
1  0  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  0  1  0
3  0  1  0  0  0
4  1  0  0  0  0
```

Now to generate a dummy for one element you can pass the index like this.

```
pd.get_dummies(categoriesSeries[4])
```

Result

```
   a
0  1
```